# Prevent left column flexbox(navigation) from scrolling together with the main content?

Tags: html, css

I have a left column that works as navigation, to it's right the main content. When I scroll in order to see more info on the main content, the navigation column starts scrolling too. How to prevent this? Make the left column work as if it had position:absolute?

```
<nav>
</nav>
<main>
</main>

body{
display:flex;
}

nav{
width:300px;
}

main{
width:100%;
padding:45px;
}
```

Comment: Cannot really do anything with the code you posted. It does not say anything about how you structured your html.

Answer (score 2):

**"cont"** div inside **Nav** contains your nav structure

```
<nav>
  <div class="cont"></div>
</nav>
<main>
</main>
```

And your css Parent Nav be

> "position:relative"

and child div be

> position:sticky and top:0

```
 body{
    display:flex;
    }
    
  nav{
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
    }

  nav>div{
    width:100%;
    position:sticky;
    top:0;
    height:2rem;
    }
    
  main{
    width:100%;
    padding:45px;
    }
```

Check here [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfmdvo3e/)

Comment: @RayRojas can I also have that approach? Thanks

Comment: it's published bro

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
body{
display:flex;
background:green;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
} 

nav{
background-color:red;
width:300px;
display:flex;
overflow:auto;
flex-direction:column;
}

main{
flex:1;
overflow:auto;
padding:45px;
}
```

Make sure your nav has enough contents in order to show scrollbar, check out this example
https://codepen.io/kingofperu/pen/mdEWrNJ